# Java - refer to implemented class

Tags: java, reference, implementation

I have a small problem: I developed an "ExampleQuest" class for my game which extends the abstract class Quest. I did this to create individual quest classes. Now my ExampleQuest class should count the death of my entities so I implemented my EntityListener. Now I have to register it in my Playstate class to make everything work but here is my actual problem: The method **Playstate.addEntityListener(this)** gives me a nullpointer exception. I found out that this error is caused **by any extended class**. If ExampleQuest wouldn't extend Quest everything works properly. There is nothing false with my Quest class because if i would extend ExampleQuest with something else, i will also get a nullpointer exception.

---> So my explanation is that the **this** from **Playstate.addEntityListener(this)** refers to the extended class in this case Quest and not EntityListener. How can I solve my problem?

```
public class ExampleQuest extends Quest implements EntityListener {

    public ExampleQuest() {
        super();
        Playstate.addEntityListener(this); //gives me nullointer exception 
    }

    //implemented method
    public void entityDeathEvent(EntityEvent e) {

    }
}
```

This is a part of my Playstate class:

```
public class Playstate {

    public static Set<EntityListener> entityListener;

    public Playstate() {
        entityListener = new HashSet<EntityListener>();
    }

    public static void addEntityListener(EntityListener listener) {
        entityListener.add(listener);
    }
}
```

EDIT: this works properly:

```
public class EventHandler implements EntityListener {

    public EventHandler() {
        Playstate.addEntityListener(this);
    }
}
```

it works because EventHandler is **only** implementing a class

Comment: Show the `Qwest` class. At least the fields and constructor.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace

Comment: There has been no `Playstate` instance created yet so the *static* field has not been assigned from the not-[yet]-called Playstate constructor. The use of static is dubious but can be "fixed" by assigning a value in the declaration (eg. `public static Set<EntityListener> entityListener = new HashSet<EntityListener>();`) or a *static initialization block* (and then removing the assignment from the Playstate constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get an NPE is that the `entityListener` has not been initialized. The reason the `entityListener` has not been initialized is that your code requires an instance of `Playstate` to be created before one could start using the `addEntityListener` method, but you call `addEntityListener` *before* creating an instance of `Playstate`.

This is wrong: *static* variables should not be initialized in *instance* constructors. You need to do it either in declarations, like this

```
public static Set<EntityListener> entityListener = new HashSet<EntityListener>();
```

or in `static` initializer blocks, like this:

```
public static Set<EntityListener> entityListener;

static {
    entityListener = new HashSet<EntityListener>();
}
```

Making `entityListener` an instance variable would work, too, but you would need to provide a way to obtain a `Playstate` instance from the context of `ExampleQuest`'s constructor.

Comment: thanks for your help :)) uff thats pretty confusing for me, i'm learning java by myself and i didn t know the static { } until now^^

Answer (score 1):

Your field `entityListener` is null because it's static, and you only initialize the field when you create an object of `Playstate`.

Probably, neither `entityListener` nor `addEntityListener` should be static.  Make them instance members.

```
public class Playstate {

    public Set<EntityListener> entityListener;

    public Playstate() {
        entityListener = new HashSet<EntityListener>();
    }

    public void addEntityListener(EntityListener listener) {
        entityListener.add(listener);
    }
}
```

**Regarding your edit:** We can only assume that when your `EventHandler` code runs, it works because you have already created a `Playstate` object somewhere else in your code.

Using a static event listener for `Playstate` means that all such objects will share event listeners, and this is a *>terrible<* idea.  Really, make them instance members, you'll be much better off.

Comment: if i would do a class like this: 

public class EventHandler imlements EntityListener {

public EventHandler() {
 Playstate.addEntityListener(this);
}
}
everything works fine because the class is only implementing not extending

Answer (score 0):

```
public Playstate() {
    entityListener = new HashSet<EntityListener>();
}

public static void addEntityListener(EntityListener listener) {
    entityListener.add(listener);
}
```

The entityListener *static* variable is assigned a value when the PlayState constructor is constructed. That is a serious design issue: either the listener is static, and thus not assoaciated to any instance of PlayState, and should thus not be assigned each time an instance is created, or it's associated to a given instance, and it shouldn't be static.

The listener, and the `addEntityListener()` method, shouldn't be static. Instead, the Quests should have a reference to an instance of the PlayState class.

Also, since it's a collection of listeners, the variable should be named `entityListeners`, and not `entityListener`.